# Sphinx scopes conditions with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm stuck here with a little problem with the scopes of sphinx using ruby on rails.

The problem is:

I need to do this scope in thinking sphinx

```
scope :for_current_user, lambda{
    {:conditions => ["documents.user_id = ? OR documents.state != 'draft'", User.current.id]}
  }
```

My most approach was:

```
  sphinx_scope(:sphinx_for_current_user){
    { :conditions => {:user_id => "#{User.current.id }", :workflow_state => '!draft'}}
  }
```

But this sphinx scope above do is a

> " documents.user_id = 20 AND workflow_state != 'draft'"

but, what i really need is

> " documents.user_id = 20 OR workflow_state != 'draft' "

Any help is well welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right query for this - without scopes - needs to be constructed manually, and might look something like this:

```
Document.search "(@user_id 20) | (@workflow_state !draft)", :match_mode => :extended
```

Currently in Thinking Sphinx, you can't supply the query as part of a sphinx scope - only options. So while the query should be fine, scopes aren't an option.